# Which element to use to modularize WPF applications?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Lets say I have a search box, which is a stack panel containing a `TextBox` and a `Button` with an icon. For easier re-usability I would like to extract said search box into a separate file.

What would I use to wrap the searchbox? I have all the functionality as attached behaviors, so I don't need any code behind.

`ItemsControl` doesn't fit, because I don't want to display items, `ContentControl` does not, because I have no content...

Could you give me hints how to fragmentalize in XAML? The only examples I find are for `ResourceDictionarys`, but not everything is a `Style`.

Comment: Create a UserControl?

Comment: @mm8
Is it ok to have multiple user controls containing more user controls? Is this overkill because I don't use the C# half of the user control?

Comment: @RubenBohnet Yes you can have User Control inside user control

Comment: A UserControl may consist of only XAML markup and an empty code-behind class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### User Control

User Controls provide a way to collect and combine different built-in controls together and package them into re-usable XAML. User controls are used in following scenarios:

- If the control consists of existing controls, i.e., you can create a single control of multiple, already existing controls.
- If the control doesn't need support for theming. User Controls do not support complex customization, control templates, and difficult to style.
- If a developer prefers to write controls using the code-behind model where a view and then a direct code behind for event handlers.
- You won't be sharing your control across applications.

### Custom Controls

A custom control is a class which offers its own style and template which are normally defined in generic.xaml. Custom controls are used in the following scenarios:

- If the control doesn't exist and you have to create it from scratch.
- If you want to extend or add functionality to a preexisting control by adding an extra property or an extra functionality to fit your specific scenario.
- If your controls need to support theming and styling.
- If you want to share your control across applications.

[source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_custom_controls.htm) (including example and more)

Comment: There is no need to create a custom control in this case.

Comment: @mm8 no it is not, but it can be useful to know when to use each one :)

Answer (score 2):

> What would I use to wrap the searchbox?

A `UserControl`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Creating a `UserControl` is a suitable model if you want to build your custom control by adding existing elements like for example `StackPanels` and `TextBoxes` to it.